# Passing down dispatch as a prop to another component

Tags: reactjs

You know how some people say that passing down a setState method is bad practice when you have a useState but say if I used useReducer instead and passed down the dispatch function instead. Would that be much better practice

Comment: Referring to some people is not constructive. It's better to pass a callback that calls setState/dispatch instead of passing them directly, this way it's easier to track what children do with them and limit the ways in which they can be used

Comment: can you provide an example for this

Comment: Also can you explain how it makes it's easier to track what children do with them and limit the ways in which they can be used

Answer (score 0):

Passing `setState` or `dispatch` allows to do anything a child wants with parent state, this is design problem. A callback can be provided from a parent instead, this way actions can be restricted to the expected usage, a breakpoint can be placed inside a callback to debug function calls if needed:

```
const increment = () => {
  dispatch({type: 'increment'});
};

...

<Child onIncrement={increment}/>
```